# Accesing field's methods in composition

Tags: java, interface, composition

I have a class Player which contains few private fields of other classes ( I believe it is called composition ).

```
public class Player
{
    private String name;
    private Statistics statistics;
    private Experience experience;
    private Effort effort;
}
```

I will post only one of them called Statistics

```
public final class Statistics
{
    Pool pool;
    Edge edge;

    class Pool
    {
        private Map<Stats, LimitedInt> map = new HashMap<>();
        private int freePoints = 0;

        void setAvailable(Stats stat, int value){}
        int getAvailable(Stats stat){ return 0; }
        void setMax(Stats stat, int value){}
        int getMax(Stats stat, int value){ return 0; }
        void setFreePoints(int value){}
        int getFreePoints(){ return 0; }
        void spendFreePoints(Stats stat, int amount){}
    }

    class Edge
    {
        private Map<Stats, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        private int freePoints = 0;

        void setMax(Stats stat, int value){}
        int getMax(Stats stat, int value){ return 0; }
        void setFreePoints(int value){}
        int getFreePoints(){ return 0; }
        void spendFreePoints(Stats stat, int amount){}
    }
}
```

It is not implemented yet of course, but I want to know what is a correct version of changing for example Player's Pool. I can imagine following scenarios:

1. Player has exactly the same methods as Pool class which are something like

   ```
   public class Player
   {
       // something above
       void setAvailablePool(Stats stat, int value){ statistics.pool.setAvailable(stat, value); }
   }
   ```

This solution seems to be ok but then in Player class I would have a lot of 1-line methods which would just redirect orders to composed fields.

2. I could transfer pool and edge to the Player class and make them public final but I read that mutable objects should be rather private.

Those 2 are my first thoughts, but I wanted to ask generally how to create interface in class when we use composition.

Answer (score 1):

One-line methods are not a problem, but what makes your solution #1 unsatisfying is the violation of the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) (statistics.pool.setXXXX). It might be better to have a statistics.setAvailableInPool() method (or to use your idea #2). I can' t offer more help with the specific implementation because It's not very clear what your Pool and Edge classes are supposed to do (or why they're so similar to each other but do not implement a common interface).

In answer to your general question about creating interfaces for composition, take a look at the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29). Basically, you should think about what behaviors you need from your dependencies, name those behaviors clearly, and depend on the interface rather than the concrete class. That makes the code easier to understand and easier to change in one place without having to change it everywhere.

Comment: Basically they don't implement common interface because one of them has more methods ( Edge does not have set/getAvailable ). What would be advance of implementing an interface in this case? I knwo Law of Demeter however in this case I would have same question as above. I have Pool and Edge in Statistics so Statistics should have something like: setAvailablePool(int value){ pool.setAvailable(value); }. Same problem.

Comment: Seems to me that comments are uneditable so I figured out why I didn't use interface this time. I just have no interest in using let's say Resources interface references. I just can't imagine why I would like to let's say store many Pools and Edges on one list as if Resources doesn;t provide Pool's additional methods Pool doesn't work as it should.

Comment: You may be able to factor out the implementation of some functionality which is common to the 2 classes.  Otherwise, it seems like you do need to differentiate between the two.

Comment: So I can make interface, make an implementation and in both Edge and Pool have this  implementation's object? It still means that due to Demeter's Law I would need to have methods which would call something like interfaceImpl.methods().

Comment: The law of Demeter is not an absolute obligation, but it's a good idea if you want to have loose coupling between collaborating objects. Once you have to know something about an object's internals you can't easily replace it with another object.  Yours may be a case where you want to think in terms of navigating through structured data rather than collaborating with objects.  In that case Demeter might not be useful.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe Pool could be a subclass of Edge because it has the same functionalities plus the idea of "Available". Also, if Pool and Edge are really distinct, I'm not sure what is the use of the Statistics class, which is just a holder for the other two.

Comment: Thanks for your answers =) The Pool is structure which represents pool of some kind of points for example 4/15 points to enxt level. You cant have it below 0 or above 15 in this case. The edge is just an Integer saying how much you can lower difficulty of task in game. So Pool is not really an Edge so it can't be it's subclass in my opinion. Maybe I shouldn't make them objects and just have: int currentPool, int maxPool, int edge in Player or Statistics. Statistics as you mentioned is rather wrapper for pool and edge just for have less fields in player class.